# Du fehlst mir so sehr

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, dative, nominative

I am confused about the translation of this sentence from Deutsch in English:

> Deutsch: **Du fehlst mir so sehr**
>   English: **I miss you so much**

Fehlen is a Dative verb but still the subject (Nominativ) keeps the first place in the sentence. So according to what I learned the translation should be:

> **You miss me so much**

Isn't it?

Comment: A semantically exact rendering of your sentence into English would be: *You are amiss to me so much*.

Comment: Since the *me* in "You miss me so much." is accusative, it could also be literally translated to "Du (ver)fehlst **mich** so sehr." which sounds very, very strange. It could mean that you misinterpreted, misjudged someboday very much

Comment: "Du fehlst mir" could probably best be translated as "You are absent/missing to me".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just English that is complicated here.

You are absent:

> You are missing.

You are absent, and I feel that:

> I am missing you.

In one case the absent person is the subject, in the other the person feeling the absence. The verb *to miss* has two different functions here.

The German verb *fehlen* does not behave that way.

You are absent:

> Du fehlst.

You are absent, and I feel that absence:

> Du fehlst mir.

In both cases the absent person (*du*) is the subject.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know who told you that stuff about subjects in first position mean something special but consider

*Rule #2 of German word order:*

- German grammar in general doesn't care about the position of items in declarative clauses.

Of course, you remember *Rule #1 of German word order:*

- The core of the predicate verb is **always the second item** in a declarative clause.

So, what's this word order thing about then?

The order of items in a clause is used for emphasis. The first item has most emphasis (it's the topic) and the last one has second most emphasis. For your example, there are six possible permutations:

> **Du** fehlst mir *so sehr*.
>
> **Du** fehlst so sehr *mir*. *(not wrong but sounds odd)*
>
> **Mir** fehlst du *so sehr*.
>
> **Mir** fehlst so sehr *du*. *(not wrong but sounds odd)*
>
> **So sehr** fehlst du *mir*.
>
> **So sehr** fehlst mir *nur du*. *(`mir du` sounds odd, hence the `nur`)*

Those sentences all mean the same thing, with different emphasis.

*You are missed by me so much.*

A good German-English dictionary will in fact translate *fehlen* as *to be missing*, and **not** as *to miss*. The latter is *vermissen* in German.

> Du vermisst mich so sehr.

*You miss me so much.*

As you can see from that, **fehlen** is a bit special. The "action" of *fehlen* is "done" by the missing person or thing (the subject), but in reality, the person/thing **does nothing**. It's just not present. That whole action is about a perception of "der Fehler" (deficit) someone **receives**. And that's why this person is the dative object rather than the subject.

Comment: Is "Du fehlst so sehr mir." and "Mir fehlst so sehr du." really not incorrect?

Comment: Vielleicht könntest du (der Klarheit wegen) noch die Übersetzung des Englischen Satzes mit dem deutschen Wort „vermissen“ (Ich vermisse dich so sehr) einbauen.

Comment: @Iris: I find them odd but at the same time I cannot nail it down to a rule which explicitly forbids it. *Mir fehlt so sehr mein Teddybär.* for example is correct and not odd sounding at all.

Comment: @Philipp: Bitteschön.